# Ipv6 to number conversion in java

Tags: java

I need to convert IpV6 address to long and vice-versa. I could not find any util or way to do this conversion. I am able to convert from IpV4 to long. But stuck in the above issue.So could you please suggest a suitable approach.

Please Help.....

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  At least not without losing information.

An IPv6 address [contains 128-bits of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address), while a `long` in Java [only holds 64-bits of information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), so any possible conversion scheme would lose information.

If you need to store an IPv6 address in Java, you should use the [`java.net.Inet6Address` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html).